# Modify a SendGoogleForm script v3

Tags: google-apps-script

I have almost got all the way now with my script but now I got stuck on an error telling me "66:    Missing semicolon". I have tried with what I can, but I do not understand.

I read about this and the semicolon should be used after a function is assigned to a variable if I understand correct, but the powershell code I put inside the "" should not be affected, right? Maybe I got this all wrong.

```
/* Send Google Form by Email v2.1 */
/* For customization, contact the developer at amit@labnol.org */
/* Tutorial: http://www.labnol.org/?p=20884 */

function Initialize() {

  var triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();

  for(var i in triggers) {
    ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(triggers[i]);
  }

  ScriptApp.newTrigger("SendGoogleForm")
  .forSpreadsheet(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet())
  .onFormSubmit()
  .create();

}

function SendGoogleForm(e) 
{  
  try 
  {      
    //Här fyller du i mailadresserna för resp avdelning.
    var it = "";

    //Ärende på mailet
    var subject = "Ny/redigerad anställning";  

    // Variables
    var test = "Test";
    var temporarypass = "Provide a Temporary Password for this user";
    var semicolon = ";";

    //Slår ihop alla mailadresser till en.
    var email = it;

    // You may replace this with another email address
    //var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();

    var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var columns = s.getRange(1,1,1,s.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];    
    var message = "";    

    // Only include form fields that are not blank
    for ( var keys in columns ) {
      var key = columns[keys];
      if ( e.namedValues[key] && (e.namedValues[key] != "") ) {
        message += key + ' :: '+ e.namedValues[key] + "<br><br>"; 
      }
      if (key == "Förnamn")
            var fornamn = e.namedValues[key];
        else if (key == "Efternamn")
            var efternamn = e.namedValues[key];
        else if (key == "Placering")
            var placering = e.namedValues[key];
        else if (key == "Titel")
            var titel = e.namedValues[key];
        else if (key == "Avdelning")
            var avdelning = e.namedValues[key];

    }

    //Output for the email that is sent.
    subject += ", " + fornamn + " " + efternamn ;
    message +="function Remove-DiacriticsAndSpaces { Param( [String]$inputString ) $sb = [Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetString([Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding("Cyrillic").GetBytes($inputString)); return($sb -replace '[^a-zA-Z0-9]', '')}; New-ADUser -SamAccountName (((Remove-DiacriticsAndSpaces -InputString '"+fornamn+"')+"."+(Remove-DiacriticsAndSpaces -InputString '"+efternamn+"')).ToLower()) -UserPrincipalName (((Remove-DiacriticsAndSpaces -InputString '"+fornamn+"')+"."+(Remove-DiacriticsAndSpaces -InputString '"+efternamn"')+"@test.com").ToLower())  -EmailAddress (((Remove-DiacriticsAndSpaces -InputString '"+fornamn+"')+"."+(Remove-DiacriticsAndSpaces -InputString '"+efternamn+"')+"@test.com").ToLower()) -Name '"+fornamn+" "+efternamn+"' -GivenName '"+fornamn+"' -Surname '"+efternamn+"' -Description '"+test+", "+avdelning+", "+titel+"' -Title '"+titel+"' -OfficePhone ' ' -Path 'OU=Users,OU=test,DC=intern,DC=test,DC=se' -Company 'test' -Department '"+avdelning+"' -Title '"+titel+"'; $NewPassword = (Read-Host -Prompt 'Provide a Temporary Password for this user' -AsSecureString); Set-ADAccountPassword -Identity '"+fornamn+"."+efternamn+"' -NewPassword $NewPassword -Reset; Set-ADAccountControl -Identity '"+fornamn+"."+efternamn+"' -Enabled $true";
    var htmlBody = "<html><p>" + message + "</p></html>";
    MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, message, {'htmlBody': htmlBody });

  } catch (e) {
    Logger.log(e.toString());
  }

}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very dense thing to follow up as this string is endless and full of brackets, but here is my try:

- Change the brackets from the word `"Cyrillic"` to `'Cyrillic'`
- There are several "stop points" without `+` (only when they are next to `"+fornamn+"')+` closing with pharentesis, the others are fine):

  `fornamn+"')+"."+(Re`

  should be

  `fornamn+"')+"+"."+"+(Re`
- Change the brackets from `"@test.com"` to `'@test.com'` or `+"@test.com"+`
- There is a missing `+` for one "efternamn": `'"+efternamn"'` to `'"+efternamn+"')`

After these changes it didn't show any other error, but I can't tell if the injected code would work.

To save you some time, here is the full string with my corrections:

````
"function Remove-DiacriticsAndSpaces { Param( [String]$inputString ) $sb = [Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetString([Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding('Cyrillic').GetBytes($inputString)); return($sb -replace '[^a-zA-Z0-9]', '')}; New-ADUser -SamAccountName (((Remove-DiacriticsAndSpaces -InputString '"+fornamn+"')+"+"."+"+(Remove-DiacriticsAndSpaces -InputString '"+efternamn+"')).ToLower()) -UserPrincipalName (((Remove-DiacriticsAndSpaces -InputString '"+fornamn+"')+"+"."+"+(Remove-DiacriticsAndSpaces -InputString '"+efternamn+"')+'@test.com').ToLower())  -EmailAddress (((Remove-DiacriticsAndSpaces -InputString '"+fornamn+"')+"+"."+"+(Remove-DiacriticsAndSpaces -InputString '"+efternamn+"')+'@test.com').ToLower()) -Name '"+fornamn+" "+efternamn+"' -GivenName '"+fornamn+"' -Surname '"+efternamn+"' -Description '"+test+", "+avdelning+", "+titel+"' -Title '"+titel+"' -OfficePhone ' ' -Path 'OU=Users,OU=test,DC=intern,DC=test,DC=se' -Company 'test' -Department '"+avdelning+"' -Title '"+titel+"'; $NewPassword = (Read-Host -Prompt 'Provide a Temporary Password for this user' -AsSecureString); Set-ADAccountPassword -Identity '"+fornamn+"."+efternamn+"' -NewPassword $NewPassword -Reset; Set-ADAccountControl -Identity '"+fornamn+"."+efternamn+"' -Enabled $true";        ```
````

Comment: Thanks Jescanellas! A big miss from my end obviously, I get so blind after looking for hours at the same issue haha. You the man!